# Clutter data - where to find for BC and how to convert to .grc

Tags: canada, data, global-mapper

I would like to find a source of 30m or 90m clutter data for BC, Canada. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Preferably a free source.

Is landcover synonymous with clutter? when downloading clutter data, how do I differentiate between grid elevation data and clutter data?  Is .lcv clutter data? could clutter data be in the form of a geotiff?  A basic primer on this would be great if anyone has any links.

I am using a radio propagation planning tool and it accepts clutter in a number of formats including .grc. I can use a tool called Global Mapper to convert to .grc if needed. Are there other/better tools to convert clutter data?

Comment: I'm not sure if clutter is synonymous with landcover because I don't know what you mean by clutter. You mention radio propagation, so I'm guessing you mean similar to 'clutter' one might see or as described on radar maps - buildings and other obstructions that block signal or provide false returns. If that's the case, it's not really synonymous - landcover means some classification of the primary features on the surface (ie forest, urban, water, or more detailed urban low density, urban high density). You'd be looking more at height and 3D object or terrain obstructions.

Comment: It's also unclear what this clutter data would look like. 30m and 90m are pretty low resolution, such that you'd be unlikely to make out individual buildings or tower-type obstructions. So would it just be a rating of how much clutter is in a given cell, as opposed to distinct objects (like a binary raster of this cell is blocked or not)? You might want to try posting this question (with some clarification) on http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you might have some data starting at $300 overlapping the us/canada border here http://mapmart.com/Products/DigitalVectorMapping/USLandCoverClutterData.aspx but there is not much in Northern BC

Comment: The clutter data as I understand it in the .grc format, essentially shows the additional "elevations" over and above the DEM due to foliage, water bodies, and man-made clutter.   So its kinda aligning with your comments on landcover.  In the 90m clutter, there were about 9 clutter classes across a given geographic area and each pixel in the area was categorized as fresh water, sea water, forest, urban, dense, urban, wetland, etc The radio propagation tool can than take this additional clutter and model the wave propagation based on various physical characteristics of the clutter category.

Comment: Yes, the higher the resolution the better.  The last project I worked on, the client did want to spend the $$ on the clutter data, they had obtained "free" 90m clutter and definitely a lot can happen between the grid points in these low resolution files.  But for the life of me, I can't recall where they got these data files from.  It was a public source.   Perhaps, they took these land cover files (.lcv) and converted to grid format using MapInfo's Vertical Mapper ?